# Postfix connected to Load Balancer, how to turn down connect/disconnect messages in mail.log

Tags: linux, postfix, logging

We have a few Postfix servers connected to our F5 Load Balancer which checks for a connection on port 25 every couple seconds to the servers to make sure it's available. Unfortunately this creates quite a lot of noise in the logs, and I'd rather watch this from the Load Balancer than from the mail server if there is a disconnect from the load balanced pool.

Here's what the messages are like, every couple seconds:

```
Oct 19 10:34:46 mail postfix/smtpd[14755]: connect from unknown[x.x.x.x]
Oct 19 10:34:46 mail postfix/smtpd[14755]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[x.x.x.x]
Oct 19 10:34:46 mail postfix/smtpd[14755]: disconnect from unknown[x.x.x.x]
Oct 19 10:34:49 mail postfix/smtpd[14755]: connect from unknown[x.x.x.x]
Oct 19 10:34:49 mail postfix/smtpd[14755]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[x.x.x.x]
Oct 19 10:34:49 mail postfix/smtpd[14755]: disconnect from unknown[x.x.x.x]
Oct 19 10:34:51 mail postfix/smtpd[14755]: connect from unknown[x.x.x.x]
Oct 19 10:34:51 mail postfix/smtpd[14755]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[x.x.x.x]
Oct 19 10:34:51 mail postfix/smtpd[14755]: disconnect from unknown[x.x.x.x]
```

I'd rather just see information related to the mail server and sending mail - but anything related to the connect and disconnect from these two IP addresses (the load balancers) I could care less about and would rather not have that spamming the logs.

What are my options here? My Postfix configuration is very bland/basic, and I'm not doing any sort of logging or debugging other than the default (except for `smtpd_helo_restrictions = warn_if_reject check_helo_access static:reject` which I'm using to track HELOs to keep us off the blacklist, but is not related to this).

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mail.contoso.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = mail.contoso.com
mynetworks = 10.0.0.0/8 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = smtp-relay.gmail.com
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_helo_restrictions = warn_if_reject check_helo_access static:reject
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Comment: `checks for a connection on port 25 every couple seconds` - Frankly I'd be changing the poll interval. Do you really need to check every few seconds? Why not every few minutes? How about two, four or 8 times an hour? How about once every 5 minutes? Honestly, why do you need to check it so often?

Comment: This is the default that the load balancer runs with, it doesn't matter in the cases of our web servers/etc. - if the server goes offline or the service abruptly stops then it will take the server out of the pool. If the service is down and the re-poll period is set to once every 5 minutes, that means that it is possible for ~4 minutes of downtime for the server, and the amount of noise in the logs is still more than is desirable.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are running defaults, this is actually a syslog question not a postfix question, as postfix sends these events to syslog, and then syslog (likely rsyslog) does the handling.

You'll want to filter out these messages:

- [Rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/discarding-unwanted-messages/)

`:msg, contains, "from unknown[x.x.x.x]" ~`

- [Syslog-ng](https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/reference-filters.html)

`@version: 3.5
filter f_F5 {message not ("from unknown[x.x.x.x]");};`

Comment: Awesome!! This is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for, looks like I had Rsyslog and set up the appropriate lines at the top of the config file and it worked.

I do have another question though - so am I understanding correctly that there is no way to change this from Postfix then? Like change the logging level from the application? Another thing that *slightly* worries me is that I may be messing up pflogsumm which I'm using for mail statistics, and I guess also truncating these lines from any sort of logs on the system at all and not just mail.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pflogsumm, it depends how it calculates statistics so I would ask a new question, the only log setting for postfix I see is debugging... if I've answered your question please accept.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, this is extremely valuable info and has greatly increased my knowledge in dealing with syslog in general. I was about to accept your answer, but there is a new post that actually has my exact scenario with the load balancer we are using and instead of not writing those logs, it does a clean connection close which prevents the need for this. I wasn't 100% what I needed to do - and didn't even realize that what I was asking for was a Syslog and not Postfix issue - but the BIG-IP Load Balancer SMTP health monitor fixes the issue for me. Thank you again

Comment: That does make sense, I haven't used F5 in years.

Comment: Used above for an AWS ELB-load balanced Postfix cluster, just slightly modified as a partial substring match against my internal VPC network subnet (`"from unknown[10.123."`)

Answer (score 3):

What monitor are you using on the BIG-IP to check the SMTP node health?  If you're using a basic TCP which only looks for a socket connection, that's fixable.

There are SMTP monitors you can configure that will run a EHLO/QUIT to cleanly close the connection.  This is another bonus because it will wait until SMTP services are available after a node reset, instead of TCP availability.

If you can, check out this: https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/difference-between-tcp-monitor-and-smtp-monitor

While you can clean out logs, it's better to fix the issue.  And remember to test this out pre-production before you drop your SMTP server accidentally.

-Chase

Comment: You're totally right that I'm using the basic TCP health monitor on the BIG-IP, I only have the built-in health monitors and had no clue that there were SMTP monitors available, it looks like you need to create one and it lets you select the type/parent monitor at SMTP. Thank you so much for the information - I will take a look at getting this switched over to an SMTP monitor from TCP.

Comment: I had the same issues with my Ironports behind LTM.  SMTP monitors cleared up a lot of issues.

Comment: I seem to be having troubles getting it to stop this in the logs when using the SMTP monitor, but maybe I need to do some more digging.